# How do you express divisions into "ones" and "twos" of larger numbers?

Tags: ordinal-numbers

When you divide something into two parts, you divide them into *halves*.
In three parts, they are divided into *thirds*.

Continuing, you get *quarters*, *fifths*, *sixths*, ..., *nineteenths*, *twentieths*.

What is the word for 21 or 22 portions, or indeed any number ending in one or two?

As a native English speaker, both *twenty-firsts* and *twenty-seconds* sound wrong. Intuitively, I want to say *twenty-oneths* and *twenty-twoths*, but these are also clearly wrong too.

Comment: What is wrong with *twenty-oneths*?  It provides a rhyme for *months*.